# If statement works on one, but not the other

Tags: python, pygame

I am using Pygame and a Buttons Module to replicate the code for a simple elevator program. I am running into the issue not displaying a certain button(created by the Buttons Module) based off of what the currentFloor is.

```
if currentFloor != maxFloor:#Checks if the currentFloor is not equal to the maxFloor
            self.Button3.create_button(self.setDisplay, colcyan, 550, 100, 200, 100,0,"Up",colblack)#Button to add one to currentLevel
```

This code provided is working for the button to go up. Although, when I attempt to recreate it using a similar line of code for the down button, It yeilds a error.

```
elif currentFloor != startFloor:#Checks if the currentFloor is not equal to the startFloor
            self.Button1.create_button(self.setDisplay, colred, 550, 400, 200, 100,0,"Down",colblack)#Button to subtract one to currentLevel
```

Error yielded:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python APCSP\Elevator\Example.py", line 72, in <module>
    obj = Elevator()
  File "G:\Python APCSP\Elevator\Example.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.runGame()
  File "G:\Python APCSP\Elevator\Example.py", line 66, in runGame
    if self.Button1.pressed(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
  File "G:\Python APCSP\Elevator\Buttons.py", line 29, in pressed
    if mouse[0] > self.rect.topleft[0]:
AttributeError: Button instance has no attribute 'rect'
```

I am unsure why a if statement very similar to the first one would provide such error.

The full source code will be provided below.

Elevator Program Source Code:

```
import pygame, Buttons, sys
from pygame.locals import *

#Color Options
colwhite = (255,255,255)
colblack = (0,0,0)
colgray = (33,33,33)
colblue = (0,61,103)
colred = (103,0,9)
colyellow = (255,229,9)
colgreen = (0,103,42)
colcyan = (0,118,118)
colpurple = (103,0,103)

#Initialize pygame
pygame.init()

currentFloor = 0
maxFloor = 5
startFloor = 0

class Elevator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.runGame()

    #Create a display
    def display(self):
        width = 800
        height = 600
        self.setDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height),0,32)
        pygame.display.set_caption("Elevator Program")

    #Update the display and show the button
    def update_display(self):
        global currentFloor
        self.setDisplay.fill(colblue)
        #Parameters:                     surface,   color,   x,   y,   length, height, width,    text,      text_color
        self.Button2.create_button(self.setDisplay, colblue, 525, 225, 250, 150,0,"Current Floor: "+str(currentFloor),colwhite)#Not a used button, just to display currentFloor
        if currentFloor != maxFloor:#Checks if the currentFloor is not equal to the maxFloor
            self.Button3.create_button(self.setDisplay, colcyan, 550, 100, 200, 100,0,"Up",colblack)#Button to add one to currentLevel
        elif currentFloor != startFloor:#Checks if the currentFloor is not equal to the startFloor
            self.Button1.create_button(self.setDisplay, colred, 550, 400, 200, 100,0,"Down",colblack)#Button to subtract one to currentLevel
        pygame.display.flip()


    #Run the loop
    def runGame(self):
        global currentFloor
        self.Button2 = Buttons.Button()
        self.Button1 = Buttons.Button()
        self.Button3 = Buttons.Button()
        self.display()
        while True:
            self.update_display()
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if currentFloor != maxFloor:
                        if self.Button3.pressed(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                            print "Going Up"
                            currentFloor += 1
                            print currentFloor
                    if currentFloor != startFloor:
                        if self.Button1.pressed(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                            print "Going Down"
                            currentFloor -= 1
                            print currentFloor

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = Elevator()
```

Buttons Module Source Code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
class Button:
    def create_button(self, surface, color, x, y, length, height, width, text, text_color):
        surface = self.draw_button(surface, color, length, height, x, y, width)
        surface = self.write_text(surface, text, text_color, length, height, x, y)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y, length, height)
        return surface

    def write_text(self, surface, text, text_color, length, height, x, y):
        font_size = int(length//len(text))
        myFont = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri", font_size)
        myText = myFont.render(text, 1, text_color)
        surface.blit(myText, ((x+length/2) - myText.get_width()/2, (y+height/2) - myText.get_height()/2))
        return surface

    def draw_button(self, surface, color, length, height, x, y, width):           
        for i in range(1,10):
            s = pygame.Surface((length,height))
            s.fill(color)
            pygame.draw.rect(s, color, (x-i,y-i,length+i,height+i), width)
            surface.blit(s, (x,y))

        pygame.draw.rect(surface, (190,190,190), (x,y,length,height), 1)  
        return surface

    def pressed(self, mouse):
        if mouse[0] > self.rect.topleft[0]:
            if mouse[1] > self.rect.topleft[1]:
                if mouse[0] < self.rect.bottomright[0]:
                    if mouse[1] < self.rect.bottomright[1]:
                        return True
                    else: return False
                else: return False
            else: return False
        else: return False
```

Answer (score 4):

The `rect` attribute is only initialised when you call `Button.create_button()`.

However, you run code in `runGame()` that expects this attribute to be present: you call `Button.pressed()` *before* calling `Button.create_button()` on button 1 or 3.

You need to ensure that the buttons are properly initialised before trying to use or query them. Or your `pressed()` method needs to check whether the button has been initialised, and return False if not.

Answer (score 0):

Call the `update_display()` function after every update to `currentFloor` .

As once `up` button is pressed value of `currentFloor` is no longer `0`.

As a result the second `if` condition (`if currentFloor != startFloor` in runGame's while loop) will also be checked but as the `update_diplay()` is not called in between so no button for `down` is initialised.

Also in `update_display()` function make both the condition as `if` as you need to check for both `buttons` no matter what.

Here is how your while loop should look like:

```
self.update_display()
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if currentFloor != maxFloor:
                if self.Button3.pressed(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    print "Going Up"
                    currentFloor += 1
                    print currentFloor
                    self.update_display()
            if currentFloor != startFloor:
                if self.Button1.pressed(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                    print "Going Down"
                    currentFloor -= 1
                    print currentFloor
                    self.update_display()
```